# Why do I have to set curSum before passing it in as a parameter?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I'm solving [Coin Change II](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change-ii/) on Leetcode and ran into a question:

I get the wrong answer if I pass in `curSum+ coins[i]` as a parameter into the recursive dfs call, but get the right answer if I set `curSum += coins[i]` and then pass `curSum` into the dfs function.

Here's the code.
This gives me the wrong solution: (test case: `target = 5, coins[1,2,5]` yields `ans: 6` (should be 4))

```
class Solution:
    def change(self, target: int, coins: List[int]) -> int:
        self.res = 0
        def dfs(i, curSum):
            if curSum == target:
                self.res += 1
                return
            if i == len(coins) or curSum > target:
                return
            
            dfs(i, curSum+coins[i])
            dfs(i+1, curSum-coins[i])
        dfs(0,0)
        return self.res
```

but this gives me the right answer(test case: `target = 5, coins[1,2,5]` yields `ans: 4` (should be 4)):

```
class Solution:
    def change(self, target: int, coins: List[int]) -> int:
        self.res = 0
        def dfs(i, curSum):
            if curSum == target:
                self.res += 1
                return
            if i == len(coins) or curSum > target:
                return
            
            curSum += coins[i]
            dfs(i, curSum)
            curSum -= coins[i] 
            dfs(i+1, curSum)
        dfs(0,0)
        return self.res
```

I'm ultimately passing in the same value, right? Why do the two codepieces behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the 2 different versions, and adding what value is acually passed to `dfs()`, assuming `curSum=1` and `coins[i]=2`:

```py
            dfs(i, curSum+coins[i])    # 1+2 = 3
            dfs(i+1, curSum-coins[i])  # 1-2 = -1
```

and

```py
            curSum += coins[i]    # curSum = 1+2 (= 3)
            dfs(i, curSum)        # passed `3`
            curSum -= coins[i]    # curSum = 3-2 (= 1)
            dfs(i+1, curSum)      # passed `1` (instead of `-1`, above)
```

In the second instance, `curSum` is updated by each `-=` or `+=`.

When in doubt, add an (e.g.) `print(f'function call: dfs({i}, {curSum})')` at the top of `dfs()`